# onClickListener does not work in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I've got some problems with the onClicklistener in the fragment. If I click on the button nothing happens at all. I get neither a message from the onClicklistener in Logcat nor does a Toast appear on the screen, but I can't find the error in the code. Any ideas?

I'd appreciate any help! Thanks a lot! And sorry for my bad english

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.util.Log;

public class InputFragment extends Fragment
{   
EditText input_text;
String text;
Button translate_button;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
    View InputFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_fgmt, container, false);

    input_text = (EditText) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.input_field);

    translate_button = (Button) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.translate);


    translate_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            Log.d("Test", "onClickListener ist gestartet");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            saveInString();

        }
    });

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_fgmt, container, false);
}

public void saveInString()
{
    if(text.equals(null))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Das Feld ist leer!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Speichern...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        text = input_text.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Fertig", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Try returning `InputFragmentView` instead of `inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_fgmt, container, false);`

Comment: Java variables name convention starts in lower case, use **inputFragmentView** instead of 'InputFragmentView'.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think problem is here in your code

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
.....
....
 //problem is here below line
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_fgmt, container, false);
}
```

return your already inflated view

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        View inputFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_fgmt, container, false);
    .....
    ....

     return inputFragmentView;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem!

Comment: I have the same issue as @reedts, but it had nothing to do with what I returned (I was returning the already inflated view). But otherwise the same - the click event is never fired it seems.

Answer (score 3):

change

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.input_fgmt, container, false);
```

to

```
 return InputFragmentView ;
```

Also change with this:

```
translate_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Log.d("Test", "onClickListener ist gestartet");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        saveInString();

    }
});
```

and import as a **import android.view.View;**

Comment: Your second statement is useless, he has already import View.OnClickListener;

Answer (score 2):

Do this changes to your code

1. on class definition:

   ```
    public class InputFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
   ```
2. on calling setOnClickListener:

   ```
       translate_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View InputFragmentView)
             {
                     Log.d("Test", "onClickListener ist gestartet");
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                    
                     saveInString();
             }
        });
   ```

Comment: You don't need to implemenet OnClickListener to the class if you are setting it manually on the button directly.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get all views created you should to redefinition the methode :

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle saved) {
    super.onActivityCreated(saved);
     input_text = (EditText) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.input_field);

translate_button = (Button) InputFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.translate);


translate_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Log.d("Test", "onClickListener ist gestartet");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Test",        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        saveInString();

    }
});
```

because this methode called after all view have been created.
you should read the life cycle of Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

`setOnItemClickListener` works with me with fragment instead of `setOnClickListener`