# Button's OnClickListener not working in a Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, button, fragment, onclicklistener

I've created a blank `Fragment` and tried to add an `OnClickListener` to a `Button` in its layout, but it doesn't seem to do anything. I'm not sure if I'm putting it in the right place or not. If I just use the `Button`'s `id` without the `view`, the app just crashes when I open this `Fragment`.

```kotlin
class CreateJobFragment : Fragment() {
        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private var param1: String? = null
        private var param2: String? = null
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            arguments?.let {
                param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
                param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            val view: View = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_job, container, false)
            view.create_btn.setOnClickListener {
                Log.d("console", "Button pressed")
            }
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_job, container, false)
        }
    
        companion object {
            @JvmStatic
            fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
                CreateJobFragment().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                        putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: To get button object from view you should use `view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.create_btn)` then you call setOnClickListener on this

Comment: ^ That, and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/18894294.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but I still doesn't work. I think it's the viewBinding that allows me to use elements with just their id.

Comment: You appear to be using deprecated synthetics, not view binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inflated your view layout once, set a click listener on the button in that layout, and then you completely throw it away, because you inflate your layout all over again and return that second layout, for which you did not set a click listener.

Change

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_job, container, false)
```

to

```
return view
```