# Button onClick in fragment to open new fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview, onclicklistener, android-tablayout

I'm working on a Bible app divided by Books -> Chapter -> Verse. When I attempted to create an onClick listener for the Book of Genesis, the button is unresponsive. I'm attempting to create a onclick inside one fragment to go to another fragment , book -> chapters.

[image: Books in Fragment with Scroll view,]

Clicking on Genesis should take me to a different scroll view fragment that contains all 50 chapters.

For context, fragment1 is the the first tab , fragment2 is second tab , fragment3 is 3rd tab

I believe the issue is with handling the onButtonSelected method in MainActivity,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements fragment1.onGenesisSelected{

private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
FragmentManager fragmentManager;
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager= findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
            FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new fragment1(),"Old Covenant");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new fragment2(),"Apocrypha");
    viewPagerAdapter.addFragment(new fragment3(),"New Covenant");
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public void onButtonSelected() {
    fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewpager,new GenesisChapters());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tablayout"
    android:layout_width="409dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OLD COVENANT" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="APOCRAPHYA" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NEW COVENANT" />
</com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>


<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tablayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:flow_horizontalBias="0.5"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have included fragment1.java where I am creating the onClicklistener for the book of Genesis

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

private onGenesisSelected listener1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
    Button GenesisBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.Genesis);

    GenesisBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener1.onButtonSelected();
        }
    });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

}
@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof onGenesisSelected){
        listener1 = (onGenesisSelected) context;
    }else{
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement listener");
    }

}
public interface onGenesisSelected{

    public void onButtonSelected();
}
```

}

fragment1.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragment1"
android:id="@+id/frag1">


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/OldCovScroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Genesis"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Genesis" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Lastly, GenesisChapters.java i.e. where the on click should send you to

```
public class GenesisChapters extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_genesis_chapters, container, false);
}
```

}

And fragment_genesis_chapters.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".GenesisChapters"
android:id="@+id/GenChapters">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/GenCh1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Chapter 1" />
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18894103

Comment: I suggest you use a Navigation component for like this as it will save you a lot :) https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: @MikeM. That helped a lot however, another issue arised within the scroll view not showing the last item (button). Even with the linear layout height as "wrap-content" , could there be another reason for this issue?

Comment: @Amjad Thanks for the tip, I will definitely take a look at that functionality, this project will get very large